# Como criar um usuário no Asp.Net Identity setando o Id que eu quiser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

Quando eu defino o Id do IdentityUser, por exemplo, para 1000, ao salvar com o CreateUser o ID fica 0.

**Observação 1:** O id da tabela aspnetusers não está como AUTO_INCREMENT.

**Observação 2:** Mudei as classes do Identity para o Id do tipo Int.

**Observação 3:** O banco de dados é mysql.